# How to reference javascript object function from onclick string

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object where I build the html and want to bind the div tag to onclick but can't seem to find the right way to do it.

```
 function person(obj){
    this.init(obj);
 }

 person.prototype = {
     init: function(){
      var html = '';
      for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
         html += '<div onclick="myFunction()">'+obj[i].name+'</div>';
      }

        $(html).appendTo('.people');

        function: myFunction(){
          console.log('hello');
        }
 }
```

What is the best way to bind myFunction() and have it work? I tried nesting the function in init() and I tried putting it at the same level as the init function. I realize that the div is not in the dom yet so it's not registering but I would like to find the best way to do this.

Comment: `$($html)` what is that selector?

Comment: Sorry should've been $(html)

Comment: Just don't use `onclick` attributes, use event handlers! Or, as you seem to be using jQuery, http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I normally do, but how do I bind it at the time of the loop? I was able to achieve what I wanted  by looping again (attaching the click event) after I append the html  but that just doesn't seem like good practice.

Comment: I wish there was an answer to this question. Using web component would be far better with declarative binding of events instead of imperative.

Answer (score 0):

If you create elements instead of HTML code, you can bind the event handler directly instead of using the `onclick` attribute that requires the function to be global. By binding it directly you can put the function anywhere that the binding code can reach, even locally inside the `init` function:

```
function person(obj){
  this.init(obj);
}

person.prototype = {
  init: function(obj){ // <- note the parameter

    function myFunction(){
      // ...
    }

    $('.people').append(
      $.map(obj, function(o){
        return $('<div>').text(o.name).click(myFunction);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. I have tried using click handlers but when I create another another object it adds another click handler. That's why I though it might be best using onClick

Comment: @bstras21: It sounds like you added the element and then tried to add an event handler using a selector to locate the element. That would also find all previous elements that you added the same way and add another handler to them. By binding the event handler directly to the element you bind it to that element only.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery, you can use it to bind a handler to `.people` elements that will fire when one of their descendant divs is clicked:

```
$('.people').on('click', 'div', myFunction);
```

You'll still get the individual div as the event target, but you limit the number of handlers on the page. This is also no longer dependent on having the divs on the page when you bind the event; as long as the `people` element is there when you bind and stays there, you can shuffle children without needing to rebind events.

Comment: The problem with this is that when I create another object it creates a another click handler, so now when I click on it, it fires twice.

Comment: Yes, you'd want to do this outside the `init` so it doesn't get called for each object

Comment: Alternatively, you could bind only the appropriate `.people` when creating an object instead of scanning the whole document on each `init`. Edit: actually, it looks like there's probably a single `.people`, so a local search doesn't solve the problem